# New member approved suggested edit!

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, new-users

I tried before to review suggested edits, but -as expected- I got this message:

> You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits.

However, and every now and then, I notice some users who have very few reputations improve or reject suggested edits!

Last example I am really very confused about is in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5933350), where [this new member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086615/aeko-sato) was able -alone- to approve my last suggested edit, although he had only 3 reputations with 4 bronze badges!

How was he (and similar users) able to do that? Is there a way to review the suggested edits or to use any other privileges even if we have few reputation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author of a question is also able to accept suggested edits.

Comment: Aha ok, that's fair enough :) Thanks for the answer!